# How do you use ctx in discord.py welcome messages?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

so I'm trying to build a discord Welcome message with an image, but when I use the following code:

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member, ctx, user: discord.Member = None):
    with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
        users = json.load(f)

    await update_data(users, member)

    with open('users.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(users, f)

    if user == None:
        user = ctx.author

    asset = user.avatar_url_as(size=128)
    data = BytesIO(await asset.read())
    im = Image.open(data)

    im = im.resize((244, 244));
    bigsize = (im.size[0] * 3, im.size[1] * 3)
    mask = Image.new('L', bigsize, 0)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(mask) 
    draw.ellipse((0, 0) + bigsize, fill=255)
    mask = mask.resize(im.size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
    im.putalpha(mask)

    output = ImageOps.fit(im, mask.size, centering=(0.5, 0.5))
    output.putalpha(mask)
    output.save('output.png')

    background = Image.open('welcome.png')
    background.paste(im, (418, 68), im)
    background.save('overlap.png')

    await ctx.send(f'Welcome {user.mention}!')
    await ctx.send(file=discord.File("overlap.png"))
```

...I get the error:

```
 await coro(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: on_member_join() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ctx'
```

I'm not sure why this is happening as I have defined ctx in the event. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can't use any other parameter than `member` in `on_member_join` event.

Comment: Does that mean there is no way to include custom welcome images in welcome messages? Or am I missing something.

Comment: Why do you need `ctx`? Isn't it just for sending message?

Comment: I use `if user == None: user = ctx.author` in my code, which uses ctx to put the pfp in the image.

Comment: How do you expect to trigger `on_member_join` event with message? You can't use `ctx` in events.

Comment: I'm not sure. I just want to be able to send a custom welcome image when somebody joins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use any other parameter than `member` in `on_member_join` event. If you want to send a message to a channel, you can use `channel.send`. For getting the channel, you can use  [`discord.utils.get`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.utils.get) or [`guild.get_channel()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.get_channel). Here is a simple example:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    channel = member.guild.get_channel(channel id)
    await channel.send(f'Welcome {user.mention}!')
    await channel.send(file=discord.File("overlap.png"))
```